# How to get rid of extra spaces in a textarea?

Tags: php, html

I am generating an HTML form, which contains some code in a text area.

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"
    rows="18" cols="40">The quick brown fox
    <?php echo $page_url;?>
</textarea>
```

When the page is rendered in a browser, it looks like this:

```
The quick brown fox
         http://www.example.com
```

I cant explain it, since the variable contains no leading spaces - and no CSS styling is being applied either.

can anyone think of what may be causing this?

Comment: does it give the same when you write it that way : <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40">The quick brown fox <?php echo $page_url;?></textarea>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitespaces inside `<textarea>` are rendered as-is, unlike HTML, which renders successive whitespace as one.

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"
    rows="18" cols="40">The quick brown fox<?php echo $page_url;?></textarea>
```

Comment: It worked!. Phew, I could have saved hours of pulling my hair out by simply asking on here... Can I just say that I am in awe of your awesomeness! :p

Answer (score 2):

Textareas respect spaces and line breaks. It's different from the behaviour of the html document itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are some spaces (or a tab) on the left of `<?php echo ..`. They will be displayed. Multiple Whitespaces wont get removed in a Textarea.

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"
    rows="18" cols="40">The quick brown fox
<?php echo $page_url ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply the fact that you indented you code...

Try that:

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"
    rows="18" cols="40">The quick brown fox
<?php echo $page_url;?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are preserved in a textarea.

```
var te = document.createElement('textArea');
te.innerHTML = 'asddf   asdf\n                  http';
document.body.appendChild(te);
```

^some test code I just ran in firebug to demonstrate

To fix you'd want something like this

```
<textarea>some test<?=$var?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need use new line inside the text area, While render it consider new line as some white space.

Answer (score 0):

The text area shows mysterious spaces because  it consider all spaces , line breaks (using enter button ) which exists beteen the `<textarea>` tags. `<textarea>

           <php? echo $var; ?>

</textarea>` after removing these extra spaces or line breaks  it should look  as following. `<textarea><php? echo $var; ?></textarea>`.